# Does a C++ STL Map move a value's location around after creation?

Tags: c++, dictionary, memory, stl, allocation

I have read some hints here and there that after inserting an object into a c++ stl map, then as long as one doesn't delete it, its location in memory never changes. But nobody ever mentioned any literature or sources to back it up, so I don't know how reliable such hints are. Can anyone answer this definately/reliably? Could it be implementation-dependent? Is there a guarantee anywhere?

Comment: hmmm. can you back that up?

Comment: The map never moves elements (at least with the default allocator). To verify, open [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and check every method that can modify the map, for all of them it should say "references are not invalidated".

Comment: According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) no interators or references are invalidated. So you should be good.

Comment: Scroll down to __Iterator invalidation__ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container  (_"...Read-only methods never invalidate iterators or references. Methods which modify the contents of a container may invalidate iterators and/or references, as summarized in this table...."_)

Comment: I was unaware iterator non-invalidation was necessarily equivalent to "the address doesn't change". but I'm convinced now for sure.

Comment: @RichardCritten modifying the contents of a map don't impact references or iterators which was the question.

Comment: @moefear Technically, **iterator** non-invalidation doesn't guarantee that the address won't change as such. **Reference** non-invalidation is what guarantees that. That said, there are no operations for any standard container that don't invalidate iterators but do invalidate references.

Comment: @doug just point to a table that answers more than just `std::map`

Comment: @RichardCritten The table you pointed to shows the same thing re map. The question was specific to map. I agree it's useful to understand the differences with other containers but the question was about map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does a C++ STL Map move a value's location around after creation?

No.

> Can anyone answer this definately/reliably?

You can rely on it.

> Could it be implementation-dependent?

It couldn't be dependent on implementation.

> Is there a guarantee anywhere?

Yes, it is guaranteed in the C++ standard:

> [container.rev.reqmts]
>
> Unless otherwise specified (either explicitly or by defining a function in terms of other functions), invoking a container member function or passing a container as an argument to a library function shall not invalidate iterators to, or change the values of, objects within that container.
>
> [associative.reqmts.general]
>
> The insert, insert_­range, and emplace members shall not affect the validity of iterators and references to the container, and the erase members shall invalidate only iterators and references to the erased elements.
>
> The extract members invalidate only iterators to the removed element; pointers and references to the removed element remain valid.
> However, accessing the element through such pointers and references while the element is owned by a node_­type is undefined behavior.
> References and pointers to an element obtained while it is owned by a node_­type are invalidated if the element is successfully inserted.